# Using scientific-notation number as int in shell script (ksh)

Tags: shell, ksh

I wish to convert string to int in shell script (ksh shell)

The string looks like 1.2E+002

Which is basically a number 120

I wanted to compare this number with say 100.

But, I am unable to do so.

Looked at other answers on stackoverflow, but none works for my case

Comment: I've tried to edit the title to be more specific -- in general (subject to exceptions, particularly in ksh) *all* variables are strings, but numbers will still be parsed as such when used in a numeric context. Scientific notation is an important case that needs separate handling, which is why this is a good question -- but it's helpful to have the title draw that detail out, since *in general* there's no need for such conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Awk's `int`:

```
$ echo "1.2E+002" | awk '{ print int($0) }'
120
```